# C++ Qt Проблемы с кодировкой(кракозябры)

Tags: c++, qt, кодировка

Написал

```
std::cout << "текст";
```

выводятся кракозябры вместо русских букв. пробовал

`setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");`

В Qt почему-то не помогает.

О программе Qt Creator:

Qt Creator 4.11.0

Основан на Qt 5.14.0

Comment: а при чём тут Qt?

Comment: Код целиком пожалуйста. Используете ли ядро Qt. В какой операционной системе работаете?

Comment: Pavel Gridin, в Code blocks setlocale помогал, в Qt - нет.

Comment: Roman Ozhegov, ОС Windows 8.1. Код целиком:
https://pastebin.com/uBFUhvQ7

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("IBM 866");
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    out.setCodec(codec);
    out << QString("текст");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Проблема решена, но у меня возник вопрос, у других вроде бы все нормально с кодировкой, я читал что у некоторых после смены кодировки на utf-8 все решалось, а мне  это не помогло. Вы не знаете из-за чего это так происходит? Спасибо.

Comment: смена кодировки на utf8 поможет только в gui (хотя можно использовать  QString::fromLocal8Bit). А консоль в винде стандартно  по прежнему 866.

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev, консоль в винде переключается, например в UTF-8 `chcp 65001`

Comment: Из командного файла кодировку вы можете так сменить хоть на традиционную китайскую, но факт остается фактом - по умолчанию кодировка консоли ibm866